# Sending integer from one class to another JAVA

Tags: java

I am changing the value of int in GUI voids and I want to send updated value to different class.

How do I return the value of `cenaKomponentow` from voids to send it?

It's still 0 because void has no return.

How to make it? I want to send value from `PCGUI class` to `Hurtownia Class`.

```
 public static int cenaKomponentow;
 public PCGUI(int cenaKomponentow) {
    this.cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow;
}

public String wybranyProc;
public JPanel getPanel1() {
    return panel1;
}

public PCGUI(){


      intelCeleron.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                intelI3.setEnabled(false);
                intelI5.setEnabled(false);
                intelI7.setEnabled(false);
                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow+200;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
                wybranyProc = ("Intel Celeron");
            }
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                intelI3.setEnabled(true);
                intelI5.setEnabled(true);
                intelI7.setEnabled(true);
                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow-200;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));


            }

        }
    });


    intelI3.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                intelCeleron.setEnabled(false);
                intelI5.setEnabled(false);
                intelI7.setEnabled(false);
                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow+300;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
                wybranyProc = ("Intel i3");

            }
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                intelCeleron.setEnabled(true);
                intelI5.setEnabled(true);
                intelI7.setEnabled(true);

                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow-300;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
            }
        }
    });

    intelI5.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                intelI3.setEnabled(false);
                intelCeleron.setEnabled(false);
                intelI7.setEnabled(false);
                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow+400;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
                wybranyProc = ("Intel i5");

            }
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                intelI3.setEnabled(true);
                intelCeleron.setEnabled(true);
                intelI7.setEnabled(true);

                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow-400;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
            }
        }
    });
    intelI7.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                intelI3.setEnabled(false);
                intelI5.setEnabled(false);
                intelCeleron.setEnabled(false);
                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow+500;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
                wybranyProc = ("Intel i7");

            }
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
                intelI3.setEnabled(true);
                intelI5.setEnabled(true);
                intelCeleron.setEnabled(true);

                cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow-500;
                cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
            }
        }
    });

    ram2GB.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            cenaKomponentow = cenaKomponentow+200;
            cenaZamowienia.setText(Integer.toString(cenaKomponentow));
        }
    });
    akceptujButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cenaKomponentow++;
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: setters, getters, callbacks???? are you familiarized with those terms?

Comment: yes i created object in class where i want to get a value but it returns 0 all time not changed value

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter method to return the int such as:

`public int getCenaKomponentow() {
    return cenaKomponentow;
}`

In the class where you want to get this int you will need to have an object of PCGUI:

`PCGUI object = new PCGUI();
int x = object.getCenaKomponentow();`

Comment: I done it before and tried, it returns 0 not nedeed value. Localy in Class PCGUI it changes but in Hurtownia it's still 0

Comment: Any ideas why ?

Comment: created object before and tried it but it's return every time value 0. I thinks thats because i change value of cenaKomponentow in void itemStateChanged? 'PCGUI siemanko = new PCGUI(); private int dawajcene = siemanko.cenaKomponentow;'

Comment: I can provide you with a sample of creating a class with an int and changing its value and retrieving it with a getter in another class ?

Comment: Man i belive you.. that's why i asked. Many diffrent int's i sended in this style. Maybe it's fault of something diffrent? Maybe i send unchanged value? Can u look at code of class up here? Maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: Yes, i will link pastebin http://pastebin.com/P27ik3qt  http://pastebin.com/cPD4GurU . As i said, it's sending 0 all time and in case of getWybranaKarta sending null :/

Comment: Ok could you now point out where in the Hurtownia you would like to retrieve the cenaKomponentow variable

Comment: Sorry i deleted it but it was in this style: cena=nowy.getCenaKomponentow(); in void addCenaKomponentow
simillary as like getWybranaKarta()